# Eclipse, how to find class dependency recursively

Tags: java, eclipse, dependencies

In Eclipse, I want to know if the specific class has indirect dependency to `javax.servlet.http.HttpSession` via it's imported dependencies. Is it possible to recursively analyze the imports and find out where the class is imported?

Comment: You want to know for a specific class or to do a full search on a project ?

Comment: specific class.

Comment: Is this a Maven project?